# Post measurement state after heterodyne measurement

Tags: quantum-optics, coherent-states, wigner-transform, quantum-measurements

I want to understand the phase space formulation of quantum mechanics better. Specifically, I am considering the following situation:

A quantum state $\rho$ on two modes can be described by its Wigner function $W_{\rho}(q_1,p_1,q_2,p_2)$. In the standard formulation of QM, one can calculate the post-measurement state on the 2nd subsystem for some projective measurement of the 1st subsystem given a certain outcome. Note that the potential entanglement between the subsystems makes this non-trivial.

I would like to do the same in the continuous-variable case: Consider a heterodyne measurement of the 1st mode where the POVM elements are the projectors $\Pi_{\alpha}=|\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha|$. Here, $|\alpha\rangle$ is a coherent state, i.e. the heterodyne measurement is a projective measurement on coherent states. 
I am looking for an expression for the resulting Wigner function on the 2nd mode.

Note that I know how to do this only for the so called quadrature measurements of $\hat{q}, \hat{p}$. For instance, measuring $\hat{q_1}$ on the first mode with outcome $m$, I calculate the post-measurement Wigner function on the 2nd mode as
$$\int dp_1 W_{\rho}(m,p_1,q_2,p_2)$$
However, I do not have the slightest idea how to generalize this to measuring arbitrary observables.

Comment: I would not call [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/368762/wigner-function-of-position-eigenket) a duplicate, but it covers the waterfront of the question you raise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a companion commentary to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/368762/wigner-function-of-position-eigenket).   It appears your confusion is on framing, and not technicalities. You are essentially asking, for one mode, $q_1,p_1$, how do you represent projective measurements in phase space, as you leave the other mode, $q_2,p_2$, alone, reducing to a reduced state.

Let's focus on the case you know. In Hilbert space, the reduced post-measurement "density matrix" is
$$
\operatorname{Tr}_1 (\Pi_m |\psi\rangle\langle \psi | ),
$$
where $\Pi_m=|x=m\rangle \langle  x=m| $, for a position measurement in tensor factor 1,  or else  what you wish, like the coherent-state projector, in general, in whatever variables you choose. You are computing the expectation value of some projector. The outcome will be a reduced state, partial density matrix $\rho_2$

The Wigner map translates this invertibly to phase space,
\begin{align}
|\psi\rangle \langle \psi| \qquad &\mapsto \qquad  h~W_\psi (q,p) \\[1em]
\Pi_m=|m\rangle \langle m|  \qquad &\mapsto \qquad   \delta (q-m) \\[1ex]
\operatorname{Tr} ( \Pi_m |\psi\rangle\langle \psi | ) \qquad &\mapsto \qquad   \int\!\! \mathrm dq \,\mathrm dp  ~  \delta (q-m) W_\psi (q,p) = \int \mathrm dp ~ W_\psi(m,p) ,  
\end{align}
as you already know. (See eqn. (137) of this [booklet](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/aaa.pdf) of ours.) For a partial trace, your just integrating the subset of relevant phase-space variables, and you are left with a reduced Wigner function $W_2(q_2,p_2)$, corresponding to a reduced density matrix.

Proceed to apply this, *mutatis mutandis* to any and all projectors of your choice, whose Wigner transform is found in the standard fashion, as for the coherent state one, $\Pi_\alpha$, in the answer linked, in any variable you choose, integrating over the (partial trace) particular variables you choose,
$\operatorname{Tr} (\Pi_\alpha |\psi\rangle\langle \psi |)=\int\!\! \mathrm dq \mathrm dp  ~  W_\alpha (q,p)  W_\psi (q,p)$.

Comment: I  am not sure about the post-measurement matrix you put. As far as I am aware $\text{Tr} (\Pi_m |\psi\rangle\langle \psi|)=p(m) $ is the probability of obtaining outcome $m$ and not the post measurement state. The post measurement state for outcome $m$ is rather given by $\frac{\Pi_m  | \psi\rangle\langle \psi | \Pi_m}{p(m)}$. So really, what you gave here are the probabilities, but not the states after the measurement? I would be very happy, if you could extend your nice analogy to the formula for the post-measurement state I stated above.

Comment: Oh... I ignored the irrelevant, unmeasured variables, $q_2,p_2$ as declared in the first paragraph. The trace is a partial trace, and the phase space integral a partial one, *only* over $q_1,p_1$. So the post-measurement outcome is *still* a density matrix, or Wigner function, as you wrote in your question, only in *fewer* variables.  Write down the *precise* Hilbert space object, and I will translate it for you.